# Can't understand client side routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I was looking into the p2p.chat.I modified it a bit to have a better room encoding technique and noise suppression based on RNN noise.

I ran the npm run bundle cmd to generate the production build and tried hosting using the express server. But I was not able to emulate the client-side routing as seen on the webpack dev output. It doesn't use react-router.
I have no idea how to host this web-app.

[p2p.chat](https://github.com/tom-james-watson/p2p.chat)

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: I don't understand your question? https://github.com/Octofun/Project-Void

Comment: and what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

okay got it fixed after replacing the contents of jam.js to this

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

I removed the directory reference in it